# setting password on pdf in appscript while expert pdf with URL?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script

pdf which was created in google-apps-script need to set a password then this pdf will be attached with email service
Is there any parameter to set a password within an export "url" before it is exported to Google drive?

```
function createPDF(ssId, sheet, pdfName) {
  const fr = 0, fc = 0, lc = 9, lr = 27;
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssId + "/export" +
    "?format=pdf&" +
    "size=8&" +
    "fzr=true&" +
    "portrait=false&" +
    "fitw=true&" +
    "gridlines=false&" +
    "printtitle=false&" +
    "top_margin=0.25&" +
    "bottom_margin=0.25&" +
    "left_margin=0.25&" +
    "right_margin=0.25&" +
    "sheetnames=false&" +
    "pagenum=UNDEFINED&" +
    "attachment=true&" +
    "gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + '&' +
    "r1=" + fr + "&c1=" + fc + "&r2=" + lr + "&c2=" + lc;

  const params = { method: "GET", headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');

  // Gets the folder in Drive where the PDFs are stored.
  const folder = getFolderByName_(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME);

  const pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob);
  return pdfFile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

Unfortunately, there is no way of setting a password of an exported Drive File, that is, by using the [Files.export method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export). That is for **pdf** files as well as other **MIME types**.

So, the password protection would have to be added (either manually or programatically) after the export from Drive.